# Flushing a pipe (os.pipe) before closing

Tags: python, pipe, ipc, buffering

I need to launch a subprocess and enable two threads for reading its `stdout` and `stderr` respectively.

The following code is just considering `stdout`:

```
def reader(rfd):
    while True:
        try:
            data = os.read(rfd, bufsize)
        except OSError:
            break
        else:
            chomp(data)

rout, wout = os.pipe()
tout = threading.Thread(target=reader, args=(rout,))
tout.start()

subprocess.check_call(command, bufsize=bufsize, stdout=wout, stderr=werr)

os.close(wout)
os.close(rout)
tout.join()
```

The code works, except I noticed that not all data is processed, as if the `os.close(wout)` function kills the reader *before* all data is read. On the other hand, if I don't close `wout` my process will be hanging forever on `tout.join()`.

I can tell this is a buffering problem because if I put a very bad `time.sleep(0.1)` just after `subprocess.check_call(...)` everything magically works.

The good way would be flushing instead of waiting, but any call to `os.fsync()` over a pipe is giving `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`.

Any hint about how to flush a pipe created with `os.pipe`?

Comment: Why are you closing the pipes *before* joining the thread?

Comment: @goncalopp, the `close` interrupts the `read`. If you do the opposite, you get a deadlock, since the thread never terminates.

Comment: Have you tried using `subprocess.Popen` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`? Also, are you sure it is not the call to close `rout` that is the problem?

Comment: @Dunes, I refrained from doing that since I know communicate buffers the whole content (in my case that would be huge). But now I realize that PIPE can be specified even when not using it. I'll try. If this works I'll let you know.

About closing `rout`, if I don't the thread gets stuck on read.

Comment: @Dacav Yes, of course - but it will process all the data, right? You just need to wait for the process to finish, and close the write ends. I'll put that in a answer in a bit

Comment: @Dunes, Thanks, it worked. If you put that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @goncalopp, I solved it, but if you put an answer I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `Popen` rather than `os.pipe` for interprocess communication.

eg.

```
writer_process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
reader_thread = threading.Thread(target=reader, args=(writer_process.stdout,))
reader_thread.start()
reader_thread.join()
```

However, if you really want to use `os.pipe` then you will have an easier time treating them like file objects. Python's in-built file context manager will make sure the files and flushed and closed appropriately.

eg.

```
def reader(fd):
    with os.fdopen(fd, bufsize=bufsize) as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(bufsize)
            if not data:
                break
            chomp(data)
```

and

```
with os.fdopen(wout, "w", bufsize=bufsize) as f:
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, stdout=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't close the pipes until you're sure the process is done writing (because you'll lose data), and you can't wait for the thread to finish without closing the pipes (because `os.read` will block forever).

You need to wait for process completion, and close the writing end of the pipe manually (since you created it).

Here's a self contained example:

```
import os
import threading
import subprocess

def reader(rfd):
    while True:
        try:
            data = os.read(rfd, bufsize)
            if not data:
                break #reached EOF
        except OSError:
            break

bufsize=100

rout, wout = os.pipe()
rerr, werr = os.pipe()

tout = threading.Thread(target=reader, args=(rout,))
tout.start()

p= subprocess.Popen("ls", bufsize=bufsize, stdout=wout, stderr=werr)
p.wait() #wait for the proces to end writing
os.close(wout)
os.close(werr)
tout.join()
os.close(rout)
os.close(rerr)
```